# Gtk:ERROR Assertion failed: accel_entry_ht == NULL

Tags: c++, opencv, gtk

Edit: Narrowed down the issue to (fails at)

```
cv::namedWindow(...)
cv::imshow(...)
```

Basically I am trying to include the opencv code snippet in my file as seen below.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include "someFile.h"


//using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int helloWorld(){
  printf("hello from CPP");

  cv::Mat image1, image2, dst;
  image1 = cv::imread("/home/gabriel/pics/opencv-logo.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
  if ( !image1.data){ 
    printf("Error loading image1 \n"); 
    return -1;}

  image2 = cv::imread("/home/gabriel/pics/opencv-test.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
  if ( !image1.data){ 
    printf("Error loading image2 \n"); 
    return -1;}

   //add( image1, image2, dst);
   // dst = image1 + image2
    cv::namedWindow( "Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cv::imshow( "Display window", image2 );

    cv::namedWindow(" Display window ", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cv::imshow( "Display window", image1 );

    //namedWindow(" Display window ", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    //imshow( "Display window", dst );

    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation with cmake runs fine (c++ opencv code wrapped/implemented in c) but throws an error when it reaches my function from c++ when running the file.

```
**
Gtk:ERROR:/build/gtk+2.0-XBK2Qt/gtk+2.0-2.24.32/gtk/gtkaccelmap.c:113:_gtk_accel_map_init: assertion failed: (accel_entry_ht == NULL)
**
Gtk:ERROR:/build/gtk+2.0-XBK2Qt/gtk+2.0-2.24.32/gtk/gtkaccelmap.c:113:_gtk_accel_map_init: assertion failed: (accel_entry_ht == NULL)
**
Gtk:ERROR:/build/gtk+2.0-XBK2Qt/gtk+2.0-2.24.32/gtk/gtkaccelmap.c:113:_gtk_accel_map_init: assertion failed: (accel_entry_ht == NULL)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Couldn't find much on this error, hoping to see where it is failing. It fails with the helloWorld() function (code runs smoothly when function is commented out)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what causes that error to happen, but it looks like that spot was updated at some point in a later version: https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/commit/f119c834c1770f183ef4722f82e9c120b3954474#diff-cad9b5941076c1782f4e9bcbbe13eb0a

gtk-3-4 looks like the first version that has that change: https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/gtk-3-4/gtk/gtkaccelmap.c

Comment: ran `dpkg -l libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0` and seem to be running on version 3.22.30. Does that mean i should try to update mine to gtk-3-4?

Comment: If the error is still happening for you, it may go away if you have the above changes. I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Yep i still have that error. Any ideas how do i go about updating my gtk version?

Comment: There may be an issue with adding those images together. There's a chance the upgrade will just mask the problem. Check out this link on addWeighted https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/dc4/tutorial_adding_images.html